# Google authentication not working when deployed to azure

Tags: c#, azure, google-authentication

I am authenticating using Google. The below code works fine when I run it locally whereas it throws an error when I deploy it to azure:

```
 HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";
                    Parameters = "code=" + code + "&client_id=" + googleplus_client_id + "&client_secret=" + googleplus_client_secret + "&redirect_uri=" + googleplus_redirect_url + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                    Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    postStream.Close();
                    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();//**Error Occurs here**
```

I also tried

```
var values = new NameValueCollection();
var resp = client.UploadValues("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?" + Parameters, values );
var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
serStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlusAccessToken>(responseString);
```

And again this worked locally, but when I deployed it to azure it didn't work

The redirect url is like below:

```
https://sample.com/Home/User?code=4/uQB37PKUFlID8dSLFFTsYLEDdHWWOprWaMtpa6YasdxxxxxxxxxxH8OQVxg3UZMoDc&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

I get the below error message and stack trace
[image]

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.]    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399
>   SomeSln.Controllers.HomeController.User() in
>   C:\CodePath\Controllers\HomeController.cs:63    lambda_method(Closure
>   , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +169
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34

Comment: can you include the full exception stack please

Comment: sure, I've added it now

Comment: any chance instead of posting images you could post the raw string values?  it makes it a pain to read and I think it is preferred option in SO.  thanks

Comment: Also please check if the 400 returned from remote server contains a message/body

Comment: @JohnB done John

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the redirect URL not being in the approved list at the **Google** side, whereas the `localhost` used when you run locally is.

Take a look at [OAuth 2.0 >> Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) for more information.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added the redirect URL and its getting redirected after the login. But fetching the token part doesn't seem to work in Azure

Comment: I suggest you try and follow the `Authorization Code Flow` example from the link I posted (as it seems from your code you are using authorization code flow) and see what's different.